# HQL multiple where clauses

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I was originally doing a single variable query and I had to add in another variable to my statement and can't seem to get it to work correctly or find a straight answer on the expected syntax. I've already checked everything is mapped correctly and nothing null is going into the query.

Here's what I'm attempting to do which isn't working correctly

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Pricing_Data where rate_class=?", rate_class + "where utility=?", utility);
```

Orginally I had it as this and that was working as expected

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Pricing_Data where rate_class=?", rate_class);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Pricing_Data where rate_class=? AND utility=?", new Object[]{rate_class, utility});
```

[Hibernate Find method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html#find%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks both of the answers helped me out ended up reformatting my query to 

"return getHibernateTemplate().find("from Pricing_Data where rate_class=? and utility=?", rate_class, utility);"

Just gotta deal with some number formatting now according to my stack trace but the query is at least going through now!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use query

```
from Pricing_Data where rate_class = ? and utility = ?
```

Then `setParameter` for `rate_class` and `utility`.

SQL/HQL queries can have second (third, etc) `where` clause only in subqueries.